# Range header broken in Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

The *Range* header doesn't seem to work correctly for files downloaded via the *export-links*. These are the request headers, response headers, and top part of the content:

```
GET /feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1dU-juYN25FMXdp6Ju62KAIT_0tuuZAPEgZkj-aT6kPQ&exportFormat=docx HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Range: bytes=0-499
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_VJ_CVLUz30Ke0zeNnhBk19y3UPo-SAnMLK5WMXUEo9a6RiTgt_ghBZRw
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Alternate-protocol: 443:quic
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-robots-tag: noarchive
Content-disposition: attachment;filename="EventDrivenIOWebApplicationServerAnalysis.docx"
Set-cookie: NID=67=AUoLJM4MRuah2izbPY5Lq_8-4bXlAlVH6N0dren6TAMFvZZo5R82VCXQvBOu9X2eIWdYf2_OeTwrq-3WH6q5uwA99CXcBDy1urLzr6fGeJUE5Pxy6EWVDG3HZLFjAz1H;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 04-Sep-2014 05:36:12 GMT;HttpOnly
Expires: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 05:36:12 GMT
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
Server: GSE
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 05:36:12 GMT
P3p: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=utf-8
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Content-location: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1dU-juYN25FMXdp6Ju62KAIT_0tuuZAPEgZkj-aT6kPQ&exportFormat=docx
PK¬dDdocProps/app.xmlÁ
Â0D¿À¹kªI[Ñ«õm
´»!»þ½A={Þð±í}Ô
2GÂZÏgVBÄ¾Ö§ãnºÒÅap!Ôú¬ÛfbdÀªk}IkcØ_`t<+é(NJÌ½¡®¶ä¯# EU-
Ü0@¦P¿ëü+
ä_ûø||¤âkì&¥!z'åd³'êP¥ÃÖük¾§'PKoð¬PK¬dDdocProps/core.xmlmÝJÄ0FÀw¹og« RÚ.*Â*z±ÌÉ¸mßÞlÑ*ì^ð9Ì|Íz´í1&í]Ë«rÅ:év}Ë_o+Î     §ñ[>aâëî¬¡>âSô#iL,\ªehù(ÔIîÐTfÂåðÃG+(cAÈOÑ#¯V`$à ,Âbä?J%eøf( hÐ¢£UYÁKm:90'ÿH«i
xý
zLza(ÍûWðöp¿O-´;T%w5i2ØÝìóì:êü²;xd¯øÎ6!-åÒÙcîm0SÒ©T^
,ó
UÝ}PKÙ)å.¶PK¬dDword/footer1.xml­TËnÛ0üþÀ»-'¢"EöbBÓ~CRk¾°¤¤øï»Ô+[Lkfgf¹^ûæöI«¤à¥59¹ÚîH"³\*'¿}Û|!Ôpª¬99On÷nº¬ ØøL³Ô!¸,M=«¦~k0H4
øUª)·aV;ä£T2ÓëÝî3mlN0Ùh±Ñõ¶QÙ²LÇ¤5¹ä`Y£   }b
BaÖøZ:?¹éKÝ¬'ö£K´ZMu[ÆvøMh5u¸Ë÷rv¼Ú­`´kZx9u¢©4³MÜÑ½Åìqh½ÕóEgáÕFê(Âùmôy¾Ô;¹j¨

Ìy«)É@]â ,;        ~GMKçeæÕªu^8qI+ ìñ÷í.Ã¿^äd7¾Èý,àð-têº(i£Â¦+ '!Üñ°¸¥QMÒ     >J#üï$·Ý5¬ZPQ4j¨zpá%ü6 «:D0Û(Ú)5\B8G~Æ¼{ñõû}|Ä²#?Qÿ4Þ¡¡èßç6þ{×³JGfuCxý_PKx÷OÛ PK¬dDword/numbering.xmlíXYnÛ0=Aï`èg¬Å²¬ AAQéh¶pÝôô¥ÖDRÐ?å|3óä£G#ßÜþælv$ ¨ãÏ=gF)ûÄùõüx;3¥H$Î+QÎíæÓÍi-r¾%`üfB¨5ÇsÐ:[»®ÂÂËcÜIàH)ì]à%Ï®°äÒtKÕ¯nàySÓÈÄÉA¬k+N1H%wºYËÝbRMÉ[<Hs"tÑÂÌ¤P©Ëfäø¯M9küNÙl) 9gÎªD'   i¥úP[FßqE1f    ÝÍJ8¢¢¥)nG¨Í=7¹ëC+©Þ6òvYHez¢[@ð:\:ã<ßÇgtÔ-î1(C{!Ï¡Àº!`ç00_HzÄµ9ÝºÎ=¦¢= îlÌ¯mõ÷Ï:³¯©)¥;2c¢fH¯DLÁm°#b»©ÊÅ#oÁ`Ê«L&òünmýyÃ
ÊÈNWpöÔØ
```

I should only get five-hundred bytes back (of content), per the docs ("partial download" section at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads).

The *Range* header works great for normal downloads. I'll get something like this in the response:

```
Content-range: bytes 0-499/11406698
```

This expresses the range that was fulfilled, and the content-length.

Answer (score 0):

No according to the API you either get 500 bytes if your range was fully valid, <500 if your range includes the EOF or 0 if your range is out of range.

Also keep in mind that neither the header containing the number of bytes total nor the use of partial download for exported documents are  a part of the **formal** documented API so should not be relied on as they may change/stop/be removed at any time.

The problem is that you are relying on **two** undocumented features at once - the answer is *don't* exported documents should be downloaded in total.

The only reasonable use for the additional information is to estimate the time to finish a download as you should not usually start processing a file until the download is **completed**.  The one exception to this is where the downloaded file is to be treated as a stream in which case you would not be able to do operations such as `seek()`.

A possible work around, (other than downloading the file completely), is to convert the document upstream and then use partial download for the resulting file but I suspect you would have to do that at file save time.

Alternatively raise a feature request to ask for this feature and keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: Yes, but the actual response (for the export-links, not the download link) disagrees with the documentation.

Comment: The old classic - don't rely on ***undocumented*** parts of the API as they *may* change or not work everywhere!

Comment: Read the original post, and my response to yours. It's documented, but broken for a *certain class* of downloads. The chunking is there for resumability. It's in everyone's interest that it works.

Comment: The problem, Steve, is that there is no way to determine, ahead of time, how large an exported file is. This is a huge problem for filesystem drivers, as OSs will often only allow you to seek through only a quantity of bytes that it knows about ahead of time. I'm wanting someone who actually has a useful workaround or some actual experience to respond... You're only sharing what I've already defined/implied as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you host a small proxy on appengine that "downloads" the full export file and then provides a partial download for it to your browser.

Comment: If I wanted to download the whole file first, I'd do it locally.